# Plotting trajectories of a 2x2 nonlinear autonomous system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As shown in Boyce and Deprima (10th Ed p. 515), one way to model the trajectories of the solution to the system of differential equations as defined below is in the case where we can find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in assuming $y$ can be defined implicitly as a function of $x$ on some interval.  Given the existence of a solution $<y(t), x(t)>$, $t$ can be defined on some "small enough" interval $I$ = $(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$ as a differentiable function of $x$ by the inverse function theorem if $x(t)$ is 1-1 on some interval. Then $y$ can be considered a function of $x$ on $I$, with derivative $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}$ given by the chain rule.

But say we have a 2x2 autonomous non-linear system of differential equations
\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dt} = f_1(x,y)\\
\frac{dx}{dt} = f_2(x,y)\\
\end{align*}
satisfying $\frac{d H(x,y)}{dx} = f_1, \frac{d H(x,y)}{dy} = f_2$.  As I understand it, the above justifies that $H(x,y) = c$ for some constant $c$ holds (if $x(t)$ is 1-1 $I$) on some interval $I$ as described above.  However, suppose we want to use this technique to plot a phase portrait for our system.  When is it valid to assume that all $x,y$ satisfying $H(x,y) = c$ are indeed the image of a solution $<x(t), y(t)>$ (a trajectory with initial conditions $<x_0, y_0> = <x(t_0), y(t_0)>$)?.

Here's what I'm asking in other words; is it normally the case that the "whole length" of a level curve of $H(x,y)$ represents the trajectory, or just some restriction of it, and when is this true?